# Run ruby-on-rails from expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, expect

I need to run a list of operations inside rails for each line of an input file.
So I thought to use expect but I'm stuck, cannot even see what rails does.
I tried just to start it and stop it and with ps I can see rails is running but there's no reaction. I see the output only when I kill rails' process

This is what I am doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set output [exec bundle exec rails c]
puts $output

spawn exit
exit
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Put your operations in an .rb file and feed it to `runner`: `bundle exec rails runner my_script.rb`

Comment: "I need to run a list of operations inside rails for each line of an input file." -- this is not what Expect is designed for. just use Ruby.

Comment: I have no experience at all in rails and needed to do a hot fix that's why I asked. I did as suggested by @SergioTulentsev, thanks